# MudTextField not rebinding value when underlying data changes

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have a MudTextField bound to a DateTime. Editing and saving the date with the MudTextField works correctly, but if I update the bound data in code the MudTextField does not change.  All other standard Blazor text boxes on that page update as expected, and I'm calling StateHasChanged on the containing razor page but the text fields refuse to show the updated data.

Is there a way to force a re-bind, or somehow force the control to refresh?  StateHasChaned on the page does not work for these controls.

I put a normal text field beside the MudTextField bound to the same data and it updates properly.

The try.mudblazor.com code is here:  https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkQQaJmnHVaRPHzM

```
<MudButton OnClick="UpdateDate"  >change date</MudButton>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-9 pt-4">
            <MudTextField T="DateTime" 
                          InputType="InputType.Date" 
                          Format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                          Margin="MudBlazor.Margin.Dense" 
                          Label="Outside Edge"
                          Variant="Variant.Outlined" 
                          @bind-value=OutsideEdgeDt/>
            <input type="text" @bind-value=OutsideEdgeDt/>
        </div>
    </div>

@code {

    public DateTime OutsideEdgeDt { get; set; } = new DateTime(2020, 2, 2);
    async Task UpdateDate()
    {
        OutsideEdgeDt = DateTime.Today;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full minimal code please - the `@code{}` and the `OutsideEdgeDate` prop. Even better; reproduce the problem on http://try.mudblazor.com

Comment: I added the mudblazor code

Comment: I'm not familiar and I will never be familiar with components libraries. However, I guess that `MudTextField` is a component, right? Then, in that case `@bind-value=OutsideEdgeDt` should be `@bind-Value=OutsideEdgeDt` Try it...

Comment: There's nothing untoward in the code, only a typo on the casing of Value for the MudTextField (and I'd surround in quotes e.g. `@bind-Value="OutsideEdgeDt"`. Don't need StateHasChanged either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enet solved it for me in the comments above.  I needed a capital V in the @bind-Value